# Uninstall pip and easy_install

Tags: python, pip, osx-mavericks, easy-install

How does one go about uninstalling pip and easy_install? I can't seem to find the documentation anywhere?  I need a clean install of both of them (long story) and rather than just overwriting them want to change them a bit.  So how exactly do I go about doing this?

Edit: Can't believe I forgot to include this, I'm running os x.

Comment: are you running windows or linux? If linux, wich linux?

Comment: Edited, os x mavricks, sorry I forgot that.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it better to install a [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) environment from scratch? Then you can install your own version of easy_install or pip. It will be also independent from your system installation. So your system applications won't be affected.

Comment: Right, I installed pip, (at least I think I did it was like 2 years ago) along with the python app (idle, launcher, etc) so shouldn't I just be able to remove it?